# In Vaadin, why, in ClickListener interfaces are the interface methods reflected as public static Method objects?

Tags: java, vaadin

Why is the interface method reflected as public static Method objects?

For example, from the Javadoc for Vaadin [Button.ClickListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/Button.ClickListener.html):

```
public interface ClickListener extends Serializable {

        public static final Method BUTTON_CLICK_METHOD = ReflectTools
                .findMethod(ClickListener.class, "buttonClick",
                        ClickEvent.class);

        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Method` instance is used for event notification. Defining it as a constant leads to more readable code in other places, and it might also have a (minor) performance benefit.

It is used when a `ClickListener` (or other listener) is registered, see for example in [`Button.addClickListener`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/24921e5f77629b4553bd1460f4e78b2296af5c94/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/Button.java#L312):

```
public void addClickListener(ClickListener listener) {
    addListener(ClickEvent.class, listener,
            ClickListener.BUTTON_CLICK_METHOD);
}
```

The reason it is used that Vaadin uses a single [`EventRouter`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/event/EventRouter.java) for all events in a component, and the dispatch is based on the event type (or event super/sub types), and the `Method` is used to look up the right method to call using reflection.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks, you don't happen to have a link to an example of how this is used do you?